# Find previous active fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have 4 fragments. Following is the navigation flow

> [Fragment 1] -> [Fragment 2] -> [Fragment 3]
>
> [Fragment 4] -> [Fragment 3]

If user goes to fragment 3 from 4 (i.e [Fragment 4] -> [Fragment 3]) on back press of [Fragment 3] it should go to [Fragment 1].

I think if I am able to find the previous fragment then It will be easy to redirect to `[fragment 1]`. Is there any way I can find what was the previous fragment that has been replaced?

I have tried fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount - 1) but is shows only one entry that is of the current fragment.

Fragment manager looks like this.

[FragmentManager Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnZE1.png)

`onBackPressed` of `Fragment 3` it  I did something like this.

```
override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    args.host.hideKeyboard()

    if (redirectToProductList) {
        args.host.activity?.let {
            if (it.supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)) {
                openFirstFragment(it, SupportFragment(MainActivity.SalesRepProduct))
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return args.host.childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onBackPressed change tabs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669199/onbackpressed-change-tabs-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. I was not adding fragment into backstack.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(newFragment.javaClass.name)
            .commit()
```

I then found previous fragment like this.

```
override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    args.host.hideKeyboard()
    val index = args.host.fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount - 2
    if (index >= 0) {
        val prevFrag = args.host.fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(index)
        if (prevFrag.name == SearchContainerPresenter::class.java.name)
            args.host.activity?.let {
                if (it.supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)) {
                    openFirstFragment(it, SupportFragment(MainActivity.SalesRepProduct))
                    return true
                }
            }
        else
            return args.host.childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
    }
    return args.host.childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user listener like this,

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container)
    //Write your logic here
}
```